# Sword-fighting, sword fighting, or swordfighting?

Tags: hyphens, orthography

Silly question, but which spelling is correct here? Like, say, "sword-fighting scenes" or "swordfighting scenes" or "sword fighting scenes".

Answer (score 2):

Google [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sword+fighting%2Csword-fighting%2Cswordfighting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) indicates that **sword fighting** is the most common of the three.

[image]

A [dictionary search](https://onelook.com/?w=sword+fight&ls=a) also shows that several mainstream dictionaries list **sword fight** but few list the other two variants.

Comment: The question is specifically about the attributive use in "sword?fighting scenes" so this Ngram isn't much use. It's common to hyphenate something attributive but use a space when it's in other contexts.